# how do i capture multiple response from server and from that i have to check specific response by JSR223 sampler in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, load, load-testing

USing WS plugin -- For single request ,server returns multiple responses in my application.

This is a gaming application. For game play request, it sends multiple response in return based on game logic.The value of attributes in response (EX: {"server":{"event":"broadcast","broadcastaction":"gamevents" --attribute broadcastaction changes)changes according to game flow. sometimes ,broadcastaction attribute is not there in response.

Multiple conditions  to be checked in my response.

So i have to capture all response  or i have to check whether the specific value is present in response using multiple if conditions in jsr223 (java) sampler.

Below is a example for response which changes as mentioned below based on game flow
Ex:

1.`{"server":{"event":"***","tr":"0"}`[image: Reference image for response]
2.`{"server":{"csh":0.0,"id":"3","action":"$$$$","value":"normal@@@@@@"}`

3.`"server":{"csh":0.0,"id":"0","action":"******","score":"-*","count":"1"},{"csh":0.0,"id":"0","action":"###","value":"***"}]}}`

4.`"server":{"csh":0.0,"id":"0","action":"******","score":"-*","count":"1"},{"csh":0.0,"id":"0","action":"###","value":"***"}]}}`

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for a [JSR223 Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Assertion) and [Groovy language](https://groovy-lang.org/) as:

1. Groovy has built-in [JSON support](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
2. It has handy shorthands to [JMeter API](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/index.html) allowing access to response data and result manipulation so you can conditionally mark sampler as passed or failed
3. It's the most performing scripting option comparing to other available languages

More information: [Scripting JMeter Assertions in Groovy - A Tutorial](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/scripting-jmeter-assertions-in-groovy-a-tutorial)